# Why my 2nd while loop in not executing?

Tags: java, while-loop

```
public void compare(ArrayList list_old, ArrayList list_new) {
        try {
            Iterator<User> iterator_old = list_old.iterator();
            Iterator<User> iterator_new = list_new.iterator();

            //Check New User Is Added
            while (iterator_new.hasNext()) {
                Log.i("Test", "inside!");
                User user_new = iterator_new.next();
                boolean NEW = true;

                while (iterator_old.hasNext() && NEW) {
                    User user_old = iterator_old.next();
                    if (user_new.getUsername().equals(user_old.getUsername())) {
                        NEW = false;
                    }
                }
                if (NEW) {
                    generateNotification(getApplicationContext(), user_new.getUsername() + " has been added.");
                }
            }
            //Check User Is Removed
            while (iterator_old.hasNext()) {
                Log.i("Test", "inside");
                User user_old = iterator_old.next();
                boolean NEW = true;

                while (iterator_new.hasNext() && NEW) {
                    User user_new = iterator_new.next();
                    if (user_old.getUsername().equals(user_new.getUsername())) {
                        NEW = false;
                    }
                }
                if (NEW) {
                    generateNotification(getApplicationContext(), user_old.getUsername() + " has been removed.");
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

1. In this function I am comparing my old list with my new list.
2. The first while loop check, is any new user added and second while loop check, is any user is removed.
3. When I am running this application only my first while loop execute and it does not execute second while loop.
4. I checked with Log.i("Test", "inside!"); and I found it does not come inside my second while loop.

Please help

Comment: Your second loop is not executing because list_new is empty.

Comment: Its not empty. If it's empty so the first while loop also should not execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to re-initialize the iterator,

```
 public void compare(ArrayList list_old, ArrayList list_new) {
        try {
            Iterator<User> iterator_old;
            Iterator<User> iterator_new = list_new.iterator();

            //Check New User Is Added
            while (iterator_new.hasNext()) {
                Log.i("Test", "inside!");
                User user_new = iterator_new.next();
                boolean NEW = true;
                iterator_old = list_old.iterator();
                while (iterator_old.hasNext() && NEW) {
                    User user_old = iterator_old.next();
                    if (user_new.getUsername().equals(user_old.getUsername())) {
                        NEW = false;
                    }
                }
                if (NEW) {
                    generateNotification(getApplicationContext(), user_new.getUsername() + " has been added.");
                }
            }
            //initialize again
            iterator_old = list_old.iterator();
            //Check User Is Removed
            while (iterator_old.hasNext()) {
                Log.i("Test", "inside");
                User user_old = iterator_old.next();
                boolean NEW = true;
                 iterator_new = list_new.iterator();    
                while (iterator_new.hasNext() && NEW) {
                    User user_new = iterator_new.next();
                    if (user_old.getUsername().equals(user_new.getUsername())) {
                        NEW = false;
                    }
                }
                if (NEW) {
                    generateNotification(getApplicationContext(), user_old.getUsername() + " has been removed.");
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: They need resetting in the nested while loops too.

Answer (score 0):

You're not resetting your iterators anywhere, so I don't think any of that code is working as you want it to. Your code would probably work and be much more readable if you used a for-each loop, which all Iterable classes support. This will avoid the need to create and reset iterators entirely.

```
for (User newUser : list_new) {
    for (User oldUser : list_old) 
        // Compare
}

for (User oldUser : list_old) {
    for (User newUser : list_new) 
        // Compare
}
```